# directive to directive communication keeps throwing error

Tags: angularjs, directive

```
angular.module("baseApp", [])
directive("theNav", [function(){
        return{
            restrict: "A",
            scope: {},
            controller: function($scope){
                $scope.showMe = {
                    isNavDisplayed: true
                }
            }   
        }
    }])
    .directive("toggleNav", [function(){
        return{
            require: "^theNav",
            restrict: "A",
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs){ 
            }
        }
    }])
```

Comment: what was the error

Comment: Please add scenario for error when it occur

Comment: okay, let me explain what I'm trying to do here, this thing is making me go crazy.

I have to independent elements with independent directvies say:

<div fristDir> </div>
<div secondDir> </div>

how do i make their directives talk to each other.
If I click a button in the first directive, i want the second directive to be displayed or hidden

Comment: You would use a `service` for this or `$broadcast` an event for which the second directive would respond.

Comment: okay, but since I'm modifying the DOM, I thought it's wise to use directives for such tasks ?